# Non Admin openstack user is unable to create compute instances on Horizon Dashboard

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

Problem Statement:
Non Admin user is unable to create instances using Openstack Horizon Dashboard.

Errors:
Errors seen in sequence on the top right of the page are:

- Error: Forbidden. Insufficient permissions of the requested operation
- Error: Unable to retrieve the flavors.
- Error: Unable to retrieve the images.
- Error: Unable to retrieve instances. Details
  Policy doesn't allow os_compute_api:servers:detail to be performed. (HTTP 403) (Request-ID: req-7c777849-af66-48dc-9b1e-48fdeaafbc5d)

Other Symptoms:

- When choosing the "Compute > Instances > Launch Instance" wizard - the use can not see the option to choose image / flavors.
- Admin user CAN choose these options and launch an instance.

Versions:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Openstack Antelope release
- 4 nodes cluster: 2 Compute, 1 Controller, 1 Storage
- This is a new, manually deployed openstack cluster

Troubleshooting done:

- Uncommented policy lines in nova_policy.yaml in /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/conf
- Restarted services, rebooted the controller node.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The horizon dashboard is not the most advanced with regards to returning useful error messages to an end-user. BTW most user facing services are designed that way, they limit what detail gets shown in error messages to end-users. That's why you need to check your log files. Also ,can your regular user create an instance when they call on the OpenStack API's with CLI tools? (to isolate if the problem is in Horizon alone or elsewhere.

Comment: What role is assigned to the user? Maybe it has only the `reader` role?